# Angular 4: Component variable dependent on another variable

Tags: angular

Alright so I'm working on something that makes an ajax call and receives a list of a bunch of messages. The messages are either processed or completed, marked by a variable isProcessed, where if it's equal to 0, it's not, and if it's 1 it is.

Anyways, I'm setting the received messages to a single variable in the component called 'messageArray'... and I have 2 separate variables called processed and completed. Those functions basically are equal to a filter of the messageArray.

However my question is, why don't these variables change when the messageArray variable changes, and how can I work around this. This is what it looks like.

```
messageArray: Array<any> = []

  processing = this.messageArray.filter((message) => {
    return message.isProcessed === 0
  });

  completed = this.messageArray.filter((message) => {
    return message.isProcessed === 1
  });
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: 
 So when the component starts, it originally has messageArray as empty, as shown by the above example, however, it also immediately uses a service to make an AJAX call to fetch a user's messages and sets the result to messageArray as so.

```
  getMessages(info) {
    let messageJSON = JSON.parse(info);

    this.messageArray = messageJSON.m
  }
```

So ideally after it sets the MessageArray with the new content, it should also change the arrays 'processing' and 'completed' as they're just filtered versions of that array.

Edit2:
 A simpler example would be this. I have two variables. One being 'x' and another called doubleX where doubleX = x * 2. What I need is when the variable x is changed, I also need this variable 'doubleX' to change to use the new value of 'x'.

Comment: Look into change detection strategy

Comment: How do you get ajax result? what do you do with it after receiving?

Comment: I have a service, my component makes a call to the service, and takes the result of it. Anyways another way to think about it is if I had two variables, one called number, and another called 'numberPlus100'. I need that variable 'numberPlus100' to change whenever number changes.

Comment: How and when is the messageArray changed? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: Show us what are you doing with the result of ajax in your component

Comment: Added further explanation in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
messageArray: Array<any> = []

processing = this.messageArray.filter((message) => {
  return message.isProcessed === 0
});

completed = this.messageArray.filter((message) => {
  return message.isProcessed === 1
});
```

This computes `processing` and `completed` based on the current value of `messageArray`, which is empty. So both of these arrays are empty, too. As you said in your question, these two arrays need to be computed when messagesArray changes. So the code should rather be:

```
messageArray: Array<any> = [];
processing: Array<any> = [];
completed: Array<any> = [];

getMessages(info) {
  let messageJSON = JSON.parse(info);
  this.messageArray = messageJSON.m;

  this.processing = this.messageArray.filter(message => message.isProcessed === 0);

  this.completed = this.messageArray.filter(message => message.isProcessed === 1);
}
```

You should also stop typing your variables as any. Use a real class or interface as the type of the elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And I do have an interface set up, I just set it to <any> as I was messing around with this problem.